# What is the shortcut for typing the current date in Microsoft Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to know what keyboard shortcuts inserts the current date in MS Word 2010.

I have tried googling but my google fu has failed me today. Hope I can get help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> keys combination for current date; also you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> if you want current time.

Note that this will insert a *field* in your word document and the date/time will update every time you open the document. To avoid this, move to the date/time filed using keys or mouse and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>, this will unlink the field making it to become plain text.

Comment: @McDonald's: thanks for the appreciation :-) If you're just curious about it, Excel's default keys combitations are `Ctrl`+`;` for current date and `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`;` for current time (and REMEMBER: keys combinations may differ if you're using a Mac!)

Comment: @Bar Akiva: some more information about word fields and their usage [here](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm) or [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-fields-in-Word-c429bbb0-8669-48a7-bd24-bab6ba6b06bb)